# using laser_filters to convert inf readings to max_range + 1 from hokuyo

Tags: ros, hokuyo-laser, hokuyo-node, laser-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a hokuyo laser sensor and I am using [hokuyo_node](http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node/) to get the Laser Scan. Then, I am using [LaserScanRangeFilter](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_filters#LaserScanRangeFilter) to filter out the readings to get max_range + 1 in cases where the hokuyo_node gives inf reading. The problem is instead of getting `max_range + 1`, I get `nan` readings for all the previous `inf` readings after running the filter. The launch file:

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="hokuyo_node" type="hokuyo_node" name="Laser_node" output="screen">
        <param name="port" value="/dev/ttyACM1"/>
        <param name="angle_min" value="-1.5707963"/>
        <param name="angle_max" value="1.5707963"/>
    </node>
    <node pkg="laser_filters" type="scan_to_scan_filter_chain" name="laser_filter">
            <rosparam command="load" file="$(find starter_node)/move_base_config/hokuyo_config.yaml" /> 
        <remap from="base_scan" to="scan" />
        </node>
</launch>
```

hokuyo_config.yaml

```
scan_filter_chain:
- name: range
  type: LaserScanRangeFilter
  params:
    lower_threshold: 0.02
    upper_threshold: 10
```

The output of `rosparam list`:

```
/Laser_node/allow_unsafe_settings
/Laser_node/angle_max
/Laser_node/angle_min
/Laser_node/calibrate_time
/Laser_node/cluster
/Laser_node/frame_id
/Laser_node/intensity
/Laser_node/max_ang
/Laser_node/max_ang_limit
/Laser_node/max_range
/Laser_node/min_ang
/Laser_node/min_ang_limit
/Laser_node/min_range
/Laser_node/port
/Laser_node/skip
/Laser_node/time_offset
/laser_filter/scan_filter_chain
/rosdistro
/roslaunch/uris/host_namankumar_inspiron_5521__45829
/rosversion
/run_id
```

I am not able to figure out what is causing it. Does anyone has any idea about how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.
Naman Kumar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209018/using-laser_filters-to-convert-inf-readings-to-max_range-+-1-from-hokuyo/) by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1464 on 2015-05-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hubble](https://answers.ros.org/users/22820/hubble/) on 2015-06-16**:
Hi ! I have the same issue as you... Have you found the solution ? Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to add the `lower_replacement_value` and `upper_replacement_value`. Else they are taken as NaN by default.

---

Originally posted by [harsha336](https://answers.ros.org/users/32137/harsha336/) with karma: 26 on 2018-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1